# many to many sqlite3 python3

Tags: python, sqlite3, many-to-many

есть две таблицы в одной находятся статьи в другой категории.
Как реализовать получение из таблицы статей всех элементов нужной категории?
пишу на python3 пользуюсь библиотекой sqlite3 (import sqlite3).

Comment: Они в разных таблицах или в разных столбцах?

Comment: Да, две созданные таблицы.

Comment: А в таблице со статьями хоть есть что то содержащее категорию есть?

Comment: в таблице id title body date category avtor

Comment: Если у вас в одной строке, то напишите так `cur.execute("select сюда столбец со статьей from ваша таблица WHERE сюда столбец в котором искать  = ?", (что искать,)) `

Comment: Понял, Спасибо!